# Visual Studio plugin to find out which files are being included implicitly

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2008

A particular header file may only be including `"Foo.h"` but `Foo.h` is including other headers which implicitly include many other headers. I would like to know all the headers that a particular file is including.

In case anybody is wondering why a *plugin for Visual Studio*; simply because of the way the include directories are set-up in the project. If an external tool does the job and allows me to specify the locations where it can search for the header files, that will do as well.

Comment: The "External Dependencies" group will show all the implicitly included headers for a project, but won't break it down by file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any plugins that do this, but you could whip up a homebrew solution by turning on the [showIncludes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk%28VS.90%29.aspx) flag in your projects settings, then doing a full build and parsing the output. The indentation changes based on the nesting of the includes.

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/wave/index.html). It is straight forward to dump all the headers included. They also have an example named list_includes that does exactly that.